# Парсинг <title> с ссылки

Tags: php, html

К примеру есть ссылка

```
https://www.olx.pl/d/oferta/cross-rfz-lizard-250-cc-26-km-raty-na-tel-dowozimy-do-domu-CID5-IDNXGSj.html?isPreviewActive=0&sliderIndex=0
```

Как сделать что бы функция возвращала

```
Cross RFZ Lizard 250 cc 26 KM Raty na tel. dowozimy do domu Czaplinek • OLX.pl
```

Смог реализовать функцию парсинга изображения с мета тега

```
function parseOLX($link) {
    $doc = new DomDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML( file_get_contents($link) );
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    $query = '//*/meta';
    $metas = $xpath->query($query);
    $rmetas = array();
    foreach ($metas as $meta) {
        $property = $meta->getAttribute('property');
        $content = $meta->getAttribute('content');
        if(!empty($property) && preg_match('#^og:#', $property)) {
            $rmetas[$property] = $content;
        }
    }

    $tags = get_meta_tags($link);
    return ["image" => $rmetas['og:image']];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Title можно получить с помощью `getElementsByTagName`:

```
$titlelist = $doc->getElementsByTagName("title");
$titlelist->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Answer (score -1):

Он вообще title не отдает:

```bsh
~ 
➜ curl -s -A 'Mozilla/5.0' -L "https://www.olx.pl/d/oferta/cross-rfz-lizard-250-cc-26-km-raty-na-tel-dowozimy-do-domu-CID5-IDNXGSj.html%5C/\?isPreviewActive%5C\=0%5C\&sliderIndex%5C\=0" | grep '<title>'

# Заголовок страницы в тегах <script> где-то
~ 
➜ curl -s -A 'Mozilla/5.0' -L "https://www.olx.pl/d/oferta/cross-rfz-lizard-250-cc-26-km-raty-na-tel-dowozimy-do-domu-CID5-IDNXGSj.html%5C/\?isPreviewActive%5C\=0%5C\&sliderIndex%5C\=0" | grep -Po '(?<=title\\":\\")[^\\"]+'
Ogłoszenia - Sprzedam, kupię na OLX.pl
Stopień wypełnienia Twojego profilu to już 
Twój profil kandydata jest już prawie gotowy
Twoje przesyłki
Panel Pracodawcy
Wygląda na to, że strona nie istnieje
Ups! Coś poszło nie tak...
Przesyłki OLX
Cross RFZ Lizard 250 cc 26 KM Raty na tel. dowozimy do domu
Cross RFZ Lizard 250 cc 26 KM Raty na tel. dowozimy do domu Czaplinek • OLX.pl
Pasuje do
Opis
To ogłoszenie nie jest już dostępne
Zaloguj się lub załóż konto na OLX, aby skontaktować się z tym sprzedającym
Zaloguj się, aby kontynuować
Zaloguj się lub załóż konto na OLX, aby skontaktować się z tym sprzedającym
Ograniczyliśmy liczbę numerów telefonów, które można zobaczyć w ciągu jednego dnia
Jeśli już teraz chcesz skontaktować się z tym sprzedającym, wyślij mu wiadomość przez OLX
Dołącz pliki
Napisz ponownie
Napisz
Wróć do Wiadomości OLX
Zgłoś użytkownika
Tak, zablokuj
Nie ma potrzeby
Tak, chcę zgłosić
Użytkownik zablokowany. Czy chcesz również zgłosić go do OLX?
Odblokuj
Zablokować tego użytkownika?
Wróć do Wiadomości OLX
Użytkownik zgłoszony
Tak, zablokuj
Nie ma potrzeby
Użytkownik zgłoszony. Czy chcesz go też zablokować?
Anuluj
Zgłoś
Chcesz zgłosić użytkownika?
Zablokuj
Zapisz rozmowę
Przenieś do kosza
Nie zapisuj rozmowy
Odsłonić ukryte informacje od sprzedającego?
Odsłonić ukryte informacje od kupującego?
Czy chcesz udostępnić swoje dane osobowe?
Wyczerpał się Twój dzienny limit nowych rozmów
Numer telefonu
Panel Pracodawcy już dostępny!
Twoje CV
Aplikowanie do nowej pracy nie musi trwać wieki
Oops! Coś poszło nie tak
Filtry
Ustawienia lokalizacji możesz zmienić w ustawieniach Twojej przeglądarki.
Poprosimy Cię o zgodę na dostęp do lokalizacji
Zlokalizowaliśmy Cię w tym miejscu
Ponów próbę
Nowość
Bądź na bieżąco z tym, co kupujesz i sprzedajesz
Nieźle:
Dobrze:
Nie polecam:
Rewelacyjnie:
```